# How to run Flask Project in QPython Android app?

Tags: android, python-2.7, flask, qpython3

I have written a code using python and Flask Framework, Which is working fine.
Now i want to run that complete code in my android phone, Qpython app is there for running python code but the problem is how to setup flask framework in Qpython app. I got some some solution for installing Flask in Qpyton but don't know the further process. Could you please help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had this similar situation before, but in my case instead of Qpython, I had Java running on the phone

there are two things you can do here,

1. Deploying your flask application to a sever, local or whatever you wanna go for and then doing an `http request` to the server *(I used heroku servers in my case but it doesn't respond somethimes as the free dyno sleeps after 30 mins of inactivity or maybe it was the **fault of Java***), basically making an Flask API.
2. Using `Firebase` for cloud [`messaging`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyfcm/1.2.4). I don't know what you are trying to achieve but it might help, to provide a gateway or so.

I hope this helps. ;)